# Excel match functions runs past end of data set

Tags: excel, match

I want to total the number of items in a column that do not match a set of values (B3:B10). The column has about 1395 rows.
I'm using this formula

=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNA(MATCH(Sheet1!F:F, B3:B10, 0)))

The output is in the millions.  Evaluating the formula, shows the comparison goes way past the end of the data set.  When pressing ctrl down arrow, I'm taken to the end of the dataset as expected.

Using Sheet1!F:F1395, results in exactly what is expected.  I would rather not define the last item in the formula to account for added rows in the future.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!F:F<>"")*(ISNA(MATCH(Sheet1!F:F, B3:B10, 0))))`

Comment: But may be quicker to do: `=COUNTA(Sheet1!F:F)-SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Sheet1!F:F, B3:B10))`

Comment: Don't mix range definition and data evaluation. Define a dynamic named range. Then use the name in your formula.

Comment: Thank you Scott!!  I used your first suggestion and it worked perfectly.  I'm avoiding the second suggestion because the return value will be used to error check the total.

Comment: Variatus, can you provide an example.  I have been interested in using variables but don't know how to incorporate them into a formula.